# Is it possible to restore my SCSS from the Sass cache files?

Tags: sass

Somehow, my blocks, foundation, and common folders got deleted. I still have my Sass cache files - is there any way I can get the original SCSS files out of them?
Currently, I am able to go through the scss-cache and grab a few styles - hope is not lost. But there's a bunch of compiled crud throughout the SCSSC file.

In the meantime, I'll be setting up a version control system for the office.

Comment: OP: answers are for answers.  Do not modify the question to contain an answer (if you feel the question will not be relevant to future users, you can always delete your question).

Comment: @cimmanon ...seriously? You delete the answer from the question just because he did it wrong? Thus making it less useful to future searchers? The least you could've done is copy it into an answer if you're going to delete it...

Answer (score 0):

Sass caches parsed documents so that they can be reused without parsing them again unless they have changed.There is no way they can be used to get the original SCSS files